# Rear wheel of child’s bicycle

Tags: wheels

This bicycle is perhaps 25 years old, I have stored it in my attic.  My wife and I recently got in down from the attic for an upcoming visit by our granddaughter. The problem is that the rear wheel does not turn when the pedal turns.  The chain is on the spokes of the rear hub and the chain turns when you 'push' the pedal but the rear wheel does not turn. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Thanks so much,

Comment: Sounds like the rear freewheel is knackered. A liberal spraying of wd40 may solve it but otherwise it’d be simpler to ask your local bike shop to take a look. They’ll likely also shoot in a lubricant to see if they can free the ratcheting pawls or give you the bad news that it’ll be more expensive.

Comment: Do you mean the chain is on the *sprocket* of the rear hub?

Comment: If this is a bike with fairly small (12" or smaller) wheels then likely the components are not standard bicycle, and something like a seized up wheel would not be unusual for one that's been stored for awhile.  Someone needs to take the rear wheel off and figure out what in it is seizing up.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus I'd guess "chain is on the teeth of the rear cog/sprocket"

Comment: Please attach photos as many as you can, it will help us to know more information.

Comment: And, one more questions, if use hand to rotate the rear wheel frontward and backward, does it roll smoothly?

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus freewheel (freehub) is a key component of the rear wheel. There're "teeth" inside the hub, and if the teeth are knackered, then the chain is not able to make it rotate. Please refer to : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freewheel

Comment: @Cray Kao I was specifically asking because the OP wrote 'The chain is on the *spokes* of the rear hub", which does not make sense. I'm quite aware of what a freewheel is, thanks.

Comment: Some of photos will help or we can only guess. Sorry, not much help. @ArgentiApparatus